# How can I add two lines (one conditional) inside an html button?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add two lines inside an HTML button, but can't seem to find anywhere what elements are allowed - I know divs, paragraphs, and breaks aren't.

What I have so far is this:

```
<button>
  Option 1
  <span ng-if="{{option2Allowed}}>Option2</span>
</button>
```

I want to be able to make Option 2 be on a different line than Option 1. 
So, if option2Allowed defaults to 'true', I have something like the following:

Option 1 
Option 2

How would I do this?

Comment: Breaks (`<br />`) are allowed in buttons.

Comment: I realise that the word 'option' might not be quite what you mean, but why are you using one button to convey two options?

Comment: The web browsers allow all elements in buttons (except for interactive elements like `input`, `select`, `textarea`, and, unsurprisingly, `button`). So you won't have any problems whatsoever with putting paragraphs, divs etc in the button. Now if it's the W3C validator you're worried about, all you have to do is use a HTML4 DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: @DavidThomas It's more like 2 lines of text, rather than 2 options. The bottom line is only visible if a condition is met.

Comment: @j08691 I was having issues adding `<br/>` inside the buttons - basically, when I did, nothing else would display

Comment: @flyingflamingo Can you link to a page that demonstrates this? I mean, `<br>`s shouldn't be a problem at all. I've used them often enough inside buttons. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ddp7yojd/), both lines are visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap both lines in a `span` tag, and set the display mode for the `spans` to `block`.  Your second line span can still have the conditional statement.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8k27g984/

Comment: Indeed I forgot to hit save.  Answer adjusted.  And yes, you are correct.  First items doesn't need the `SPAN`.

Answer (score 1):

CSS tables perhaps might suit?

```css
button {
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
button span {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>Option1</span>
  <span>Option2</span>
</button>

<button>
  <span>Option1</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This is what I would call abusing a table.

Comment: Technically, it's not a table.

Comment: But this does change the button into a block element. Normally, `one <button>two></button> three` is displayed on one line; not so with your solution. And I don't like CSS tables consisting of only rows, not cells. And it's overkill. And the spans can no longer have paddings or borders or whatever.